# How to switch to my newly forked repo without losing my changes

Tags: git, github

Afraid of losing my local changes, I need your help in this scenario:

- Cloned a github repository (https://github.com/nikitar/newt.git)
- Applied local changes to this repo
- Would like to push my changes to my newly forked repo (https://github.com/adko-pl/newt), which I have created after cloning the `newt` repository.

How can I switch to my newly forked repo and be able push my changes without losing my local changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Pushing changes to other repositories

You can add your fork as a remote:

```
git remote add myrepo git@github.com:adko-pl/newt.git
```

and push the `branch` in wich your changes were commited to it

```
git push myrepo branch
```

#### Creating feature branches

I recommend you commit your changes to a branch that is not one of the main branches in the original repository (`master` in this case) but in a topic branch. Forming a pull request and keeping up with the history from the original repository will become much easier that way.

```
git branch feature-x
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
git checkout feature-x
```

#### Naming remotes

As a general rule, I name my own repositories `origin` and the original one `upstream`

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote rename myrepo origin
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is really helpful, BTW. shouldn't `git add remote` be `git remote add`?

Comment: Yes, it should be. Fixed it. :-D

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, also thanks for the suggestion regarding feature branches.

Comment: Agree. Stick to naming your remotes origin and upstream